# How to hide sheets in your excel file that are not filled in

Tags: vba

I have an excel that hides certain sheets when opening the document. So like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Worksheets("screen_2").Visible = xlHidden
    Worksheets("screen_3").Visible = xlHidden


end sub
```

Now I have the case that someone fills in either sheet "screen_2" or "screen_3". Right now when someone has filled in either screen_2 of screen_3 sheet closes the document and reopen the excel sheet "screen_2" and "screen_3" are not visible.

What I would like to achieve is that the first time you open the excel document both sheets should be hidden but that when you fill in one of the two sheets that particular sheet should not be hidden when reopening the excel file.

So when I open the excel sheet and fill in screen_2, save, close en reopen the file "screen_2" sheet should be visible (and screen_3 hidden) and when I open the excel doc and fill in screen_3, save, close en reopen the file "screen_3" sheet should be visible (and screen_2 hidden)

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Comment: if the first time these two sheets are hidden, how can it be the user fills them?

Answer (score 2):

once you get through how to fill a hidden sheet, then you could use:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    CheckIfHideSheet Worksheets("screen_2")
    CheckIfHideSheet Worksheets("screen_3")
End Sub

Sub CheckIfHideSheet(sht As Worksheet)
    With sht
        If .UsedRange.Address = "$A$1" And IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then .Visible = xlHidden
    End With
End Sub
```